# Jeep 2007 liberty wont start, trans temp light up on dash

Tags: jeep, liberty

So yesterday I took my Jeep 2007 Liberty to AutoZone and had him put the diagnostic thing on it and it told me the speed sensors on three wheels were bad okay so then today I drive it to my daughters I go out to get in it and it won't start it doesn't click it doesn't do anything at all could that possibly have done something to it

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do the dash lights light up when you turn it on?